# How can JWT be verified outside the authorization server

Tags: jwt, self-contained

Recently, I'm trying to implement an OAuth2.0 server using JSON Web Token (JWT) as access token. I'm very confused about the self-contained feature of JWT. I notice that JWT can be verified anywhere, not mandatorily in authorization server because it is self-contained. How does this feature work? What claims should be included in JWT in order to realize self-contained feature?

Another question is that, if JWT is stateless, it means the server should not store the JWT. Then how is the JWT verified? Can't it be easily forged?

I'm the rookie in this field, I wish someone could help me out:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JWT contains claims that can be signed, encrypted or both.
These operations are performed using cryptographic keys. Keys can be symmetric (e.g. `oct`et keys) are Asymmetric (e.g. private/public key pairs such as `RSA` or `EC` keys).

When you want to verify a JWT (i.e. a JWS), you have to perform the following steps:

- Check the header (algorithm is supported, critical claims are in the payload and their value are understood).
- Check the claims (especially `exp`, `iat`, `nbf`, `aud`).
- Check the signature.

To check the signature, you need the key and, depending on the algorithm, this key can be

- The symmetric key
- The public key if asymmetric

When you want to allow third party applications to verify your JWT, you will use asymmetric keys and share the public key with the third parties.
As public keys cannot be used to sign, third parties cannot forge a valid token with custom claims.

The way you share the keys is up to you. The common way is to provide an URL where applications will retrieve them (e.g. Google keys at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand the process much clearly now. I have another question, is the expiry time the only way to reduce the loss of token leakage? I think if the token is stored in mobile devices, it would be easily stolen by malicious applications. Is that right?

Comment: Yes it can be stolen, but if the token expired it cannot be used anymore. That is why a short lifetime is highly recommended

Comment: Thank you, I now know JWT well.