# Why is the access token generated by IdentityServer4 always invalid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4

I am trying to setup a fairly basic identity oAuth server using IdentityServer4 on asp.net core 3.1. I've created a basic project and using inmemory configuration.

I can request and receive a bearer token (client credentials flow), but whenever I make an introspection call, I receive a 401 response. I suspect it has something to do with the token itself - trying to verify it using some of the online websites always seems to show an invalid token.

My code, Starup.cs:

```
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(InMemoryConfig.GetApiScopes())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryConfig.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(InMemoryConfig.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfig.GetUsers())
                .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfig.GetClients())
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

InMemoryConfig.cs:

```
        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() =>
            new List<Client>
            {
               new Client
               {
                    ClientId = "myclient",
                    ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("dev-$he turned me into a newt!".Sha512()) },
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    AllowedScopes = { IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        "read",
                        "write",
                        "update",
                        "delete"}
                }
            };


        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes() =>
            new List<ApiScope> { 
                new ApiScope("read", "read data"),
                new ApiScope("write", "write data"),
                new ApiScope("update", "update data"),
                new ApiScope("delete", "delete data")
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources() =>
            new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("partnerservices", "Partner Services")
                {
                    ApiSecrets = new [] {new Secret("PSSecret")},
                    Scopes = { "read","write","update","delete"}
                },
                new ApiResource("coreservices", "Core Services")
                {
                    Scopes = { "read","write","update","delete"}
                },
                new ApiResource("mysite", "My Site")
                {
                    Scopes = { "read","write","update","delete"}
                }

            };
```

Here is the token I obtained:

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEwQkZDNjQ5NTM2NkU0NTc2NjlDNkEzN0VBOTczQjAwIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJuYmYiOjE2MDQ3MDA0NjAsImV4cCI6MTYwNDcwNDA2MCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzMTEiLCJhdWQiOlsicGFydG5lcnNlcnZpY2VzIiwiY29yZXNlcnZpY2VzIiwibXlzaXRlIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im15Y2xpZW50IiwianRpIjoiNjYyOTIzQjNGQkY4QzU4QTg2OTBCM0NFNjkxNzZFQTkiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDQ3MDA0NjAsInNjb3BlIjpbImRlbGV0ZSIsInJlYWQiLCJ1cGRhdGUiLCJ3cml0ZSJdfQ.Troia38tgbAR18VMC47UosniAVW8Iq6PwtksX2bOeEClm42_koYsw8_JBZ97i9nk5b9W0liGsQO0AEgukiNIDbeihHI4zMBGSM2y3ZJw-09g7mttbRVFIgPuD_4u7bJi57zZLTdAF6jg_9vxHhHbp2aAH7uXLMgsZB8qpCH9_hJnoxd5r8OKKFBL9wlOSYtnh-D8a0bKH_VnTZxn28Ozt4NJ06PxuqvcC_GEnAHmbSajeDGtPkIhvGhTU2Nd7nHtv9EvBoS__wXsvefgSpv-yCaGZMFc58Abv_LO_WqHsSTbl8eayk6ayoVShiWYh_5Ei5gVmcyCQAF1SO1X8qkGJw",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "delete read update write"
}
```

...and here is the public key info returned from  "jwks_uri": "https://localhost:44311/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks in my discover docs:

```
{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","use":"sig","kid":"10BFC6495366E457669C6A37EA973B00","e":"AQAB","n":"0Zq2wamtiFtqhNNqlY4rYyC1nbO1hB1ztXIhYJc7tjhhpsyViXyWlKiD8cORmHieO8sH4ZSXCeQbYV7u1nXI7SG28ul9kozpUO7M9vf1nOv50o9mZg_BOyMFnTgcDMN6zjT1IWM9K5NY-2D7jSZvxQo4GNwWr2SpytRXLYAgWSHgj3wDarZIXfHKmIRSYvS8L6d_2G0dbxWD699VQMRz0WBjRR6qwhlXc4-4dSeBfvrioWf0DA6LD2NGNA1oP1XWuV_Htkh2Ay5Ck4AyUc3xbC4TVI3SpuhYMK_3zuHwmnzA1L4SyXnHG963hXpbDSUtu01i3YTK2v5MterR9PFWzQ","alg":"RS256"}]}
```

If you're still reading this, thanks already! The issue is that I cannot make a subsequent introspect call using that bearer token, nor can I validate that token using any of the online validators (e.g. jwt.io)

What am I missing?

for completeness, here is my introspect call:

```
> POST /connect/introspect HTTP/2
> Host: localhost:44311
> authorization: Basic ZXRyYWMtY2xhcmlmeTpldHJhY2Rldi0kaGUgdHVybmVkIG1lIGludG8gYSBuZXd0IQ==
> user-agent: insomnia/2020.4.2
> content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> accept: */*
> content-length: 796

| token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEwQkZDNjQ5NTM2NkU0NTc2NjlDNkEzN0VBOTczQjAwIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJuYmYiOjE2MDQ2ODkxMTgsImV4cCI6MTYwNDY5MjcxOCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzMTEiLCJhdWQiOlsiZXRyYWMtcGFydG5lcnNlcnZpY2VzIiwiZXRyYWMtY29yZXNlcnZpY2VzIiwiZXRyYWMtbGlua2QiXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiZXRyYWMtY2xhcmlmeSIsImp0aSI6IjNGQzQ0NzE4QTAyMzcyRUFBOUFDMDUzOEQyNjQyMDk5IiwiaWF0IjoxNjA0Njg5MTE4LCJzY29wZSI6WyJkZWxldGUiLCJyZWFkIiwidXBkYXRlIiwid3JpdGUiXX0.iDl8MEgqRcgFdg3T-rST9jTIxGJfwMtGQ-a6nSAxOadqs8P0EM_UcCYVwKhuzjNM4uORbrhsD5XDB2wMtgMEaSgNdKlH5NA2OTRkftFAKyii2M0ihQL06rN1KVURKySK4d38pezuQxZ48blDaro5ae8RUxMOkRlsPwX6e6LBKeJ2MkqmKcj6AJ1b0sDkJpdgagy4gjvBGWcQOAf_TuEobaWBEKEdzF_gM0a321PDFayCTuezc7bIYN5eq4VQL3-PINbOq72Cashjmi4BCNF0sV-gKq1blDMEZ6UcN-jGOUaaEtvh36H8bHw2H-mY1535tPpX4PzpE_zB6mtHvpJScA
```

Answer (score 1):

It all looks good, the code I use to make manual introspection calls looks like this below using the Flurl.Http NuGetp package:

```
/// <summary>
/// Introspect an access token
/// </summary>
/// <param name="accessToken">The received access token</param>
/// <param name="apiName">The name of this API-Resource as defined in Identity Server</param>
/// <param name="apiSecret">the API secret as defined in the API-Resource</param>
private void IntrospectToken(string accessToken, string apiName, string apiSecret)
{
    //Get the Introspection endpoint URL

    var url = new Url(openIdConfig.IntrospectionEndpoint).WithBasicAuth(apiName, apiSecret);

    var introspectionResult = url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(new
    {
        token = accessToken

    }).ReceiveString().Result;

    //Console.WriteLine("\r\nintrospection Result");
    //Console.WriteLine(introspectionResult);
}
```

Perhaps it can give some clues?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the validation with jwt.io. Actually the result is [Signature Verified](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEwQkZDNjQ5NTM2NkU0NTc2NjlDNkEzN0VBOTczQjAwIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJuYmYiOjE2MDQ3MDA0NjAsImV4cCI6MTYwNDcwNDA2MCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzMTEiLCJhdWQiOlsicGFydG5lcnNlcnZpY2VzIiwiY29yZXNlcnZpY2VzIiwibXlzaXRlIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im15Y2xpZW50IiwianRpIjoiNjYyOTIzQjNGQkY4QzU4QTg2OTBCM0NFNjkxNzZFQTkiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDQ3MDA0NjAsInNjb3BlIjpbImRlbGV0ZSIsInJlYWQiLCJ1cGRhdGUiLCJ3cml0ZSJdfQ.Troia38tgbAR18VMC47UosniAVW8Iq6PwtksX2bOeEClm42_koYsw8_JBZ97i9nk5b9W0liGsQO0AEgukiNIDbeihHI4zMBGSM2y3ZJw-09g7mttbRVFIgPuD_4u7bJi57zZLTdAF6jg_9vxHhHbp2aAH7uXLMgsZB8qpCH9_hJnoxd5r8OKKFBL9wlOSYtnh-D8a0bKH_VnTZxn28Ozt4NJ06PxuqvcC_GEnAHmbSajeDGtPkIhvGhTU2Nd7nHtv9EvBoS__wXsvefgSpv-yCaGZMFc58Abv_LO_WqHsSTbl8eayk6ayoVShiWYh_5Ei5gVmcyCQAF1SO1X8qkGJw&publicKey=%7B%22kty%22%3A%22RSA%22%2C%22use%22%3A%22sig%22%2C%22kid%22%3A%2210BFC6495366E457669C6A37EA973B00%22%2C%22e%22%3A%22AQAB%22%2C%22n%22%3A%220Zq2wamtiFtqhNNqlY4rYyC1nbO1hB1ztXIhYJc7tjhhpsyViXyWlKiD8cORmHieO8sH4ZSXCeQbYV7u1nXI7SG28ul9kozpUO7M9vf1nOv50o9mZg_BOyMFnTgcDMN6zjT1IWM9K5NY-2D7jSZvxQo4GNwWr2SpytRXLYAgWSHgj3wDarZIXfHKmIRSYvS8L6d_2G0dbxWD699VQMRz0WBjRR6qwhlXc4-4dSeBfvrioWf0DA6LD2NGNA1oP1XWuV_Htkh2Ay5Ck4AyUc3xbC4TVI3SpuhYMK_3zuHwmnzA1L4SyXnHG963hXpbDSUtu01i3YTK2v5MterR9PFWzQ%22%2C%22alg%22%3A%22RS256%22%7D). Most likely you entered the keys array, not the only **element** into the *Public key* field.

Next, you do not have to use introspection for JWTs. They are for validation in place. Please read [the first googled SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39657314/1426685) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
In my case, the context that needs to verify the signature does not have access to any tools to do so. The toolset can make http requests out, but does not have the ability to verify the signature itself. One alternative is to write my own endpoint that this toolset can hit to verify the signature - but it seems like the introspection endpoint is already intended for that purpose. So, why should I have to write my own? Anyway, thanks again! Not sure what I was doing that made it seem not verified.

Comment: ...in any case, I think the 401 error for my introspection request is not saying that the token is invalid. I think it's simply failing to authorize the request prior to validating the token. I cannot figure that out.