# Access token does not include scopes declared in Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, identityserver4, access-token

Following roughly [Scott's](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4) guide, I got it to work with authorization code flow. However, When I investigate the well-known, I see that *junky_scope* is listed as supported. My client and API scope/resource are declared as follows. The claims in the access token are to be based on the API scopes according to [IDS4's GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/678#issuecomment-272166032).

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> Obtain()
{
  yield return new ApiScope("junky_scope", "Junky Scope"); ...
}

yield return new ApiResource
{
  Name = "blopp", ...
  Scopes = new List<string> { "awesome_scope", "junky_scope", ... }
};

yield return new Client
{
  ClientId = "spa_client",
  AllowOfflineAccess = true,
  AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code, ...
  AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "openid", "awesome_scope", "junky_scope" }
};
```

Invoking the call to exchange my code for token, produces a valid access token but only containing *openid* and *offline_access* scopes, though. The same when requesting a new one using the refresh token. The payload passed in the body is shown below. I've tried with no *scope* specified to get all of the supported tokens (as promised [in the docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html#token-endpoint)) with no success.

> client_id=spa_client
> &scope=junky_scope
> &redirect_uri=http://localhost:44304/beep
> &code=205D...EDBF
> &grant_type=authorization_code

The setup is very similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722267/why-is-the-access-token-generated-by-identityserver4-always-invalid) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387069/identity-server-4-adding-claims-to-access-token), although they regard different matters. The scopes declared are shown as included in the response, though.

I thought at first it may have to do with the definition of my test users but there's nothing about claims there and the closest I can see is claims. But I don't rely on claims in my scope, so that's a dead-end.

I'm lost and not sure how to troubleshoot it further. Googling variations of *ids4 access token scope no included* produced very little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a big fan of answering my own questions but on occasion, it's called for.

Apparently, there's a bug in IDS4 (or, at least a highly unclear spot in [the documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html)). It states as follows.

> ***scope***
> *One or more registered scopes. If not specified, a token for all explicitly allowed scopes will be issued.*

That is incorrect, hence my confusion leading to the question.

---

Now, if I'm to defend IDS4 docs, [it is said](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html) also that the parameter is required for the authorization (not the exchange nor renewal) request.

> ***scope***
> *One or more registered scopes (required).*

Now, besides it being a clear discrepancy and listed on different pages, if we interpret *explicitly allowed scopes* as those that are referenced during the authorization and not in the server's clients, API scopes/resources, then yes, the docs are not wrong. But that's a deep dive in spagat from where I stand, to make that plausible as obvious.